# Why is IDENTITY UNIQUE allowed in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Why is this

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
   OrderID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) UNIQUE,
   BuyerID INT,

   PRIMARY KEY(OrderID, BuyerID)
);
```

allowed in SQL Server?

I mean, why is `IDENTITY(1, 1) UNIQUE` allowed?

Doesn't `IDENTITY` already mean that the values are going to be unique?

It's like static const in C# - const is already static (static const isn't allowed in C#).

Comment: it's just another constraint. Identity can be disabled for inserts, allowing you to give it explicit values....hence, you can have duplicates. It's just not the same

Comment: ***NO!*** `IDENTITY` alone does ***NOT*** say anything about uniqueness! If you fiddle with the identity values (like using `DBCC RESEED` and such), there's nothing in the `IDENTITY` column code that stops SQL Server from issuing a value that's already been assigned before. .....

Comment: What *is* disallowed is specifying `UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY`. There's no technical reason preventing a primary key constraint and a unique constraint from both being defined on a column, but SQL Server will nevertheless disallow it because there's no point. Duplicate indexes are otherwise fine, even if they're exactly the same, and you can even put a unique index on a primary key column if you're so inclined. This is more in line with your `static const` example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `IDENTITY` doesn't mean the values will be unique. You can reset the seed of the identity column which will give you duplicates. Or you can enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` which will allow you to put your own values in.

And `IDENTITY` is referring to how the values are generated, whereas `UNIQUE` is adding a constraint. 2 different concepts.